How to preserve Created Date and Modified Date while migrating datas from Azure blob to gcp
I have some containers in Azure which has folders/file which has to be migrated to gcp buckets from Azure .
I want to preserve Created Date of files( files created in Azure) using Metadata when moved to GCP
add a new metadata recording the original creation time

To preserve the created date and modified Date of files while migrating from Azure Blob Storage to GCP, you can use the metadata feature in GCP. You can add a new metadata field to each file that records the original creation time of the file in Azure.
To add metadata to a file in GCP using the gsutil use something like this- gsutil setmeta -h "x-goog-meta-original-created: 2024-07-27T11:00:00Z" gs://your-gcp-bucket-name/your-object-name
You can also use the  -r  option with the  gsutil setmeta  command to add metadata recursively to all files in a directory.

How to get the file created date from Azure ?While migrating files from azure to gcp , I want to preserve the file created date in Azure.
